# Can I use GoogleMaps behind a pay-wall?

Tags: google-maps

I'm thinking of using maps as a better/more interactive way of displaying information about certain countries.

As I work for a subscription company, the maps would sit behind a pay wall. Only those who pay our subscription would be able to access the pages with the interactive maps.

Can I use GoogleMaps for this? Is it allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial):

> **Can I use the Google Maps API on a commercial website?**
>
> As long as your
>   site is generally accessible to consumers without charge, you may use
>   the Google Maps API. For example, if your website is supported by
>   advertising, it likely falls within the Google Maps API Terms of
>   Service. If you charge people to place information on your map (e.g.
>   to list their homes for sale), but you display this information using
>   the Google Maps API on a free part of your site, you'll also meet the
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service.
>
> However, not all commercial uses are allowed. For example, if your
>   site meets any of the following criteria you must purchase the
>   appropriate Google Maps API for Work license:
>
> - Your site is only available to paying customers.
> - Your site is only
>     accessible within your company or on your intranet.
> - Your application
>     relates to enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset
>     tracking, or similar applications.

As your site is only available to paying customers, you will likely need to purchase an API license.